# How to parse this JSON in C++ Builder?

Tags: c++, json, c++builder

I have the following JSON:

```
{"test1":"1", "test2": {"test21":"21", "test22":"22"}}"
```

but I'm having troubles parsing it. Actually, I'm somehow trying to read "test21" but don't know how to reach it. I tried this but it's not good:

```
UnicodeString myJSON = "{\"test1\" :\"1\",\"test2\":{\"test21\":\"21\",\"test22\":\"22\"}}";

TJSONObject *JSON = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(myJSON);
TJSONValue *test2 = (TJSONValue*)JSON->Get("test2");
//TJSONString* test21 = (TJSONString*)test2->Get("test21");
```

Comment: Why is it "not good"?

Comment: It doesn't give good result.

Comment: And what is "not good" about the result? What is it?

Comment: As I wrote: I don't know how to read "test21" value. The code I wrote can only isolate the whole "test2" block but the commented part gives memory exception when I try to use it to read "test21".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```cpp
TJSONObject *JSON = (TJSONObject*)TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(myJSON);
TJSONPair *pair = JSON->Get("test2");
TJSONObject *jsonObj = (TJSONObject*) pair->JsonValue;
TJSONPair *test21 = jsonObj->Get("test21");
String value = test21->JsonValue->ToString();
```

Comment: Working as it should! Thanks.